# error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of scala.collection.Map[String,Long]

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried all the possible ways by importing all possible libraries and checking out answers for all the questions related to saveAstextFile or saveAsSequenceFile havn't even helped. Hence initiating a new thread.
I am getting an error "error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of `scala.collection.Map[String,Long]      countResult.saveAsTextFile("tmp/testfile").` While trying to save an rdd to HDFS. I am following below steps.

```
1.scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

2.scala> val countrdd = sc.parallelize(Array( "hadoop","spark","hadoop","spark")).map( k => (k,1))
countrdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[17] at map at :28

3.scala> val countResult = countrdd.countByKey()
countResult: scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(spark -> 2, hadoop -> 2)

4.scala> countResult.saveAsTextFile("tmp/testfile")
:33: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of scala.collection.Map[String,Long]
countResult.saveAsTextFile("tmp/testfile")
```

Note: I am using Spark 2.X version on standalone cluster.

Comment: `saveAsTextFile` can be applied to an `RDD` not to a regular scala collection.

Comment: Thanks Glennie , what I understood is we can use save function only on rdd created with transformation not with actions.

Comment: Well, you action (`countByKey`) does not yield a result of type `RDD`, but rather a normal scala collection of type `Map[String,Long]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method like `saveAstextFile` is only available with `RDD`.
You can perform any number of transformation if it is `RDD` then you can use a method like this

**But** if you had applied any `action` like `countByKey` then the method like this will no longer will be available.

Instead of `countByKey` you can use the `reduceByKey` here You can find more detail about this [here](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) under RDD API Example Section.

Or you can try this code:-

```
val countrdd = sc.parallelize(Array( "hadoop","spark","hadoop","spark"))
val findRDD = .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Hope this clears your issue

Thanks